# Computing $\int \tan(x)\,dx$ using Euler's formula

Tags: integration

I attempted to integrate the $\tan(x)$ function by substituting the Euler's formula into $\tan x = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$. Integration resulted in the expression $\ln(2\cos(x))$, which is obviously not correct, since integrating $\tan(x)$ should produce $-\ln(\cos(x))$. I used the substitution $t=(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$, and when I inserted $\ln(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$ as the solution to the integral into Wolfram|Alpha, it gave me the result $-\ln(2\cos(x))$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please learn to [typeset your math correctly](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This will make it easier for users to read your question and come up with a response. I see you are new to MSE--welcome! Your question is good in that it shows effort (nice job), but it really does need to be typeset nicely.

Comment: The expression $\log(2\cos x)=\log(2) +\log(\cos(x))$.  Antiderivatives can differ by a constant.  The concern is the minus sign, not the appearance of the 2.  If you show your analysis herein, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Wow, that was something I that really didn't cross my mind. Thank you very much for helping me and if I ever ask a question on this site again I'll remember to show my own analysis of the problem as well.

Comment: I really just want to help, so please let me know if I can improve my answer.  I want to give the best answer I can!

Comment: @JohnDoe I just cleaned up your question. Please see the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1209192/revisions) to see what all I did and take a look at the link I originally posted. It's imperative that you typeset your questions correctly. Honestly, I oftentimes don't even read questions that are very poorly typeset. Just a friendly tip.

Answer (score 5):

Using Euler's identity, the integral of $\tan(x)$ is

$$\begin{align}
\int \tan(x) dx &= \int \frac{\frac{1}{2i} (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{\frac{1}{2} (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})} dx \\
&=-i\int \frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})} dx \\
&=(-i)(-i)\int \frac{d\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)}{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}\\
&=-\log(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})+C\\
&=-\log(2\cos(x))+C\\
&=-\log(\cos(x))+C'
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}dx=\int \frac{-\frac{d}{dx}\cos x}{\cos x}dx=-\int \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\cos x}{\cos x}dx=-\ln|\cos x|+c.$$

Comment: The OP evidently knows how to do this.   The question related to the difference between the correct result and the one obtained using another approach.

Comment: @Dr.MV The OP knows the correct answer but he's getting a different answer. My aim is to show a way to get the correct answer.

Comment: @AlexR To the contrary ... Read the OP.  The OP obtained the correct result using the standard approach.  The OP didn't obtain the known result upon using Euler's identity!

Comment: @mfl  To the contrary ... Read the OP.  The OP obtained the correct result using the standard approach.  The OP didn't obtain the known result upon using Euler's identity!

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, you are right.

Comment: @mfl No worry.  Best sincere wishes going forward!